# How do I customize timepicker to only show/set hours 1-12 without (am/pm and minutes) API 19 and disable Listeners

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

i want to use a TimePicker to show the position of a medical phenomenon in context to the human body.

Example: Person A has a wound on his right foot at 7 o'clock. (For picture of right foot inner side)

For this I want to use a TimePicker that uses the clock display and only enable hours from 1-12 and disable the am/pm picker and the minute picker.

Second problem I need to use API 19 which does not support set/get hours/minutes. (Saw that while testing, don't know if that affects more methodes from timepicker due to API 23 req.)

To test this i added a time picker in an example project:

**activity_main.xml** :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id ="@+id/edit_Message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:timePickerMode="clock" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The timepicker above has the hours, minutes and am/pm picker and also has a digital and radial clock to pick the time directly (no wheel). That is allready the form I want.

For picking time I can switch from hours to minutes by clicking the digital clock or by clicking on the radial clock (selecting an hour sets hours and swiches to minutes, which also switches the analoge clock from 1-12 to 00 - 55.)

I want to disable the switch from radial clock clicked (hours->minutes) and disable the minute part on the digital clock.

Under http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html I didn't find anything usefull that could point me to a solution.

So i looked at the timepicker via debugger and accessed the "components" of the timepicker individualy.

From **MainActivity.java**:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TimePicker picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    picker.setIs24HourView(false);
    LinearLayout pickerLL = (LinearLayout) picker.getChildAt(0); //only child of timepicker
    RelativeLayout digitalRL = (RelativeLayout) pickerLL.getChildAt(0); //child 0 is digital clock, child 1 is radial clock
    AppCompatTextView minutesTV = (AppCompatTextView) digitalRL.getChildAt(2); //TextView of minutes
    minutesTV.setClickable(false);
    //minutesTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    LinearLayout ampmLL = (LinearLayout) digitalRL.getChildAt(3); // Layout of the am / pm picker
    ampmLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            //Put the change for timepicker hour here
        }
    });

}
```

So i was able to make minutes not clickable and am/pm picker invisibil (gone).

How do i find the Listener that switches the radial clock from hours to minutes?

Comment: Why do you wnat to allow only 12 hours per day? It doesn't make sense so far...

Comment: In medicin you use the measure hours to locate things and those go from 1-12. If you have a human 12 o'clock would be the head while 9 o'clock would be the right arm etc. This is just for convinience (people working in medicine are used to that so i want to apply it in the app as well for usability purpose). So the clock is not acctually of the value "time" but "location".

Comment: Thanks your code helped me much to hide minutes